# Is Ubuntu automatically bootable?

Tags: boot, compiling

I'm just wondering if if I'm going to have to build a disc or write a disc.

If I need to build a disc in order to make it bootable, can you give me some instructions on how to do so? I'd most likely be using Imgburn, but if you would recommend a different burner, I'll gladly take suggestions.

Comment: Yes, I believe you mean "burn image to disk" as building, right? As just placing the .iso into a data disk "write[ing] to disk" will not boot.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, most official Ubuntu images are bootable if properly burned to a disc or copied to a USB storage device.

The official Ubuntu download page has links for how to both burn a DVD and create a USB install device.

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Answer (score 1):

No. Just copying the contents of ISO to USB won't make it bootable.You need to BURN it on that USB(Or more specifically some files needs to be copied on zero'th sector of that USB) ;)

In ubuntu you have preinstalled application `usb-creator-gtk` for this purpose. You just need the iso of ubuntu version and a USB with atleast 1GB capacity.
For this open terminal (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>) and enter

`usb-creator-gtk`

If you are on windows then you should try [LiLi](http://www.linuxliveusb.com/)(Live Linux usb creator).